Problem optimizing a product of a row method in C
compute2 is SOMEHOW slower than compute1?!
I have no idea what even my name is at this point
double compute2(unsigned char data[H][W]) 
{

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int k=0; k<H; k++) {
        double tmp = 1.0;
        for (int j=0; j<W; j++) {
            tmp *= (A / (data[k][j] + B));
        }
        sum += tmp;
    }

    return sum;

}

double compute1(unsigned char data[H][W]) 
{
    double *rowProduct = malloc(sizeof(double) * H);
    for (int k=0; k<H; k++) {
        rowProduct[k] = 1.0;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<W; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<H; j++) {
            rowProduct[j] *= (A / (data[j][i] + B));
        }
    }

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int k=0; k<H; k++) {
        sum += rowProduct[k];
    }
    
    free(rowProduct);
    
    return sum;
}

This completely broke my brain any help please and thank you....
this is how data is populated:
void initializeData(unsigned char data[H][W]) 
{
    for (int i=0; i<W; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<H; j++) {
            data[j][i] = rand() % N;
        }
    }
}


I suspect that the form of compute1 allows the compilers vectoriser to use SIMD instructions much more effectively. You might also want to try swapping the for i, for j loop order around to see which way is actually faster.

Please [edit] and post a [mcve].

... also [edit] and show how you compile and which compiler/platform/OS/versions etc. you use.

Maybe compile into assembler code, that might give some insights.

I'll bet the addition loop in compute1 can be compiled into a single vector addition instruction.

Try to compile with -ffast-math on GCC/Clang and it should solve your performance issue. FP-number operations are not associative. This not only prevent compilers to use SIMD instruction but also limit the CPU to execute instructions in parallel too. Note that -ffast-math can be dangerous though.

@Barmar This is not so simple since data[j][i] accesses are not contiguous one. SIMD gather instructions exists on SIMD instruction sets like AVX2/AVX-512 but they are pretty inefficient on some platform (AFAIK AMD CPUs) and sometimes cause compilers not to generate SIMD code. The default instruction set on x86-64 (SSE) and ARM (Neon) does not even have gather instructions. This is why specifying the compiler name/version/flags and the target CPU are so important (and unfortunately missing here).

@JérômeRichard I was talking about sum += rowProduct[k];

How are A and B defined?  And what about H and W — presumably, they're integer constants.  What about N?  Read about how to create an [mcve].

@Barmar This loop should take a negligible time. The 2 nested loops is the bottleneck. Even if it would be, associativity prevent compilers to vectorize that (see my comment above).

The nested loops are almost identical in the two scripts. The only difference is whether it assigns to the temporary tmp variable or rowProduct[j]

@Barmar No, they are pretty different, at least for compilers. In the first, tmp is the same variable modified j times and a long dependency chain. In the second, rowProduct[j] are different items for each iteration without dependency chain. The long dependency chain with a significant latency is very likely what makes the OP code slow. Besides, the former access data contiguously while the later does not. Details matters for performance.
